# Get Retweets count using usertimeline (retweets of me)

Tags: java, twitter

I want to count re tweets counts for different screen name using single access token and consumer key etc.
so, because of that I am using APi - GET statuses/user_timeline. to extract all its statuses and trying to identify retweets count from that.
Actually, i have used APi - GET statuses/retweets_of_me for retweets counts but it is only working for the account for which access token and etc is available. but i want to download retweets count for other user account also.
How we can distinguish between or find exact - retweets_of_me from user timeline response.
Beacuse from user timeline i am getting all type of statuses. but i want only retweets of me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by retweet count? How many times a particular tweet has been retweeted? How many times a user has been retweeted in total? A little more information would be helpful.

Comment: How many times a particular tweet has been retweeted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how many times a specific tweet has been retweeted, it's very easy.

You want to use statuses/show - [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid).

Here's one of my tweets:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=224808742712115200
```

You will see that one of the parameters in the returned JSON is

```
"retweet_count":5
```

That means, the tweet was retweeted 5 times.

You **do not** need to be authenticated in order to make this API request.